# Loop through For Loop certain number of times

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop

Okay, I know the question is a bit ambiguous but here I go. I have a dynamic form with 4 inputs. These dynamic fields on the form can generate multiple times.

[image]

What I intend to achieve is this the input field repeat with amount 100 is supposed to be inserted 4 times same as amount 200 and same as amount 300 so in total, I should have a total of 12transactions with the different amounts there. I already have the code set up for inserting the dynamic field into the database excluding the repeat input field. I cannot seem to wrap my mind as to how I can do the above explanation. Please Help

```
        $bulkRecipientTransfer = $Request->bulkRecipientTransfer; //array
        $bulkTransferType      = $Request->bulkTransferType; //array
        $bulkAmountTransfer    = $Request->bulkAmountTransfer;//array
        $bulkCountTransfer     = $Request->transferCount; //array 

for( $i =0; $i < count($bulkRecipientTransfer);) {
            
            $commandId = MpesaB2B::query()->where('id',$bulkTransferType[$i])->pluck('commandID')->first();
             
            $this_contact = array(
    
                $bulkRecipientTransfer[$i],
                $bulkTransferType[$i],
                $bulkAmountTransfer[$i],
                $bulkCountTransfer[$i]

                );

            $_amount = $bulkAmountTransfer[$i];
            $_bulkRecipientTransfer = $bulkRecipientTransfer[$i];
            
            $CountTransfer = $bulkCountTransfer;

                     $insertData = [
    
                            'AccountReference'  =>$narration,
                            'TransactionAmount' =>(int)str_replace(',', '', $_amount),
                            'Status'            =>0,
                            'credit_party'      =>$_bulkRecipientTransfer,
                            'debit_party'       =>$sender,
                            'CommandID'         =>$commandId,
                            'SystemType'        =>'externalbulk'
                            ];
                        
    
                        B2BTransfer::insert($insertData);


            }
```

Comment: is your code working ?

Comment: Yes the Code works without the input field labeled repeat.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get that. Could you please explain bit

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to implement _two_ loops, one inside the other. Not sure why that is a problem, though.

Comment: @arkascha thank you for your response. Thats what i want problem is how do i finish one value on the repeat field for the one transaction then perform the other.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha what i mean is as shown on the image. if a user keyed in the repeast field value eg 5 and the amount is 100 and the next dynamic field has a repeat value of 6 and amount 100 it means in total we will have 11 transactions

Comment: so you need to use JQuery to achive this one.Can we see the html part

Comment: @NipunTharuksha capturing the values is not a problem. Problem is the backend

Comment: mmm sorry but if this works whats is the issue in backend ?

Answer (score 1):

For the second loop, this may work. I am not sure if I got your question correctly though. This would allow you to add each of those entries four times into the database.

````php
for( $i =0; $i < count($bulkRecipientTransfer);) {
            
            $commandId = MpesaB2B::query()->where('id',$bulkTransferType[$i])->pluck('commandID')->first();
             
            $this_contact = array(
    
                $bulkRecipientTransfer[$i],
                $bulkTransferType[$i],
                $bulkAmountTransfer[$i],
                $bulkCountTransfer[$i]

                );

            $_amount = $bulkAmountTransfer[$i];
            $_bulkRecipientTransfer = $bulkRecipientTransfer[$i];
            
            $CountTransfer = $bulkCountTransfer;
                     $insertData = [
    
                            'AccountReference'  =>$narration,
                            'TransactionAmount' =>(int)str_replace(',', '', $_amount),
                            'Status'            =>0,
                            'credit_party'      =>$_bulkRecipientTransfer,
                            'debit_party'       =>$sender,
                            'CommandID'         =>$commandId,
                            'SystemType'        =>'externalbulk'
                            ];
                        
    
            for($j = 0; $j < $CountTransfer; $j++) {
                        B2BTransfer::insert($insertData);
            }


            }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Okey, thank you all for your assistance on this. Well due to client pressures and issues with timelines i had to find a way out of this by doing the following;

```
        for($i=0; $i< count($bulkRecipientTransfer); $i++){

            $stagingTransfer = new MpesaStaging;
            $stagingTransfer->credit_party = $Request->bulkRecipientTransfer[$i];
            $stagingTransfer->debit_party = $Request->sender;
            $stagingTransfer->AccountReference = $Request->bulkNarration[$i];
            $stagingTransfer->TransactionAmount = (int)str_replace(',', '', $Request->bulkAmountTransfer[$i]);
            $stagingTransfer->Status = 1;
            $stagingTransfer->SystemType = 'externalbulk';
            $stagingTransfer->CommandID = $Request->bulkTransferType[$i];
            $stagingTransfer->repeatCount = $Request->transferCount[$i];
            $stagingTransfer->save();


        }

        //Fetch the stored transactions here

        $fetchStaging = MpesaStaging::query()->where('Status',1)->get();


        foreach($fetchStaging as $key=>$queue){

             $transactionCountStart      = 1;
             $TransactionAccountRefDate  = date('dmy');

            for($i=0; $i < $queue->repeatCount; $i++){

               $commandId = MpesaB2B::query()->where('id',$queue->CommandID)->pluck('commandID')->first();

                $transferSchedule = new B2BTransfer;
                $transferSchedule->AccountReference  = $queue->AccountReference.$transactionCountStart++.$TransactionAccountRefDate;
                $transferSchedule->TransactionAmount = $queue->TransactionAmount;
                $transferSchedule->Status       = 0;
                $transferSchedule->credit_party = $queue->credit_party;
                $transferSchedule->debit_party  = $queue->debit_party;
                $transferSchedule->CommandID    = $commandId;
                $transferSchedule->SystemType   = $queue->SystemType;
                $transferSchedule->save(); 

            }

            $updateScheduledPayments = MpesaStaging::query()->where('id',$queue->id)->delete();
        }
```

1. Capture the Number of dynamic rows generated. Then Store them on a staging table.
   Extract the RepeatCount captured for each transaction Amount and use a for loop to process the RepeatCount number of transactions to be queued.Then delete the already processed staged transaction based on the queue id.